# php/mysqli query not executing some of the query's with no errors

Tags: php, mysql, execution

I have a script running every minute on my server to do basically a cron job to update some variables in the database for a small game i am making for some friends.

The issue i am having is that the script only runs some query's but fails to update others. i have verified that it is connecting but a comparison is not working. any help would be appreciated.

this is my current call that is not working.

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
//Query server
$query = "SELECT id, usr, dt, is_online FROM player_data WHERE is_online =1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// If connection is good
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) 
    {
        echo "Connected </br>";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            //Get time of NOW, and time of last activity
            echo "loop started </br>";
            $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")));
            $before = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['dt'])));
            //Add five minutes to the last activity
            $then = $before + (60 * 5);
            //Display the times
            echo $before . "</br>";
            echo $now . "</br>";
            echo $then . "</br>";
            //determine if the time now is more then 5 minutes after the last activity
            if (strtotime($now) > strtotime($then))
                {
                    //set user to offline if more then 5 minutes has passed.
                    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE player_data SET is_online = 0");
                    echo "1.User: " . $row['usr'] . "</br>";
                    echo "1.Database: " . $row['dt'] . "</br>";
                    echo "1.System: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "</br>";
                    echo "Now: " . $now . "</br>";
                    echo "Before: " . $before . "</br>";
                    echo "then: " . $then . "</br>";
                }

        }

    }
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
this should set anyone who has not been active in the last 5 minutes to is_online = 0 but does not.

This is the actual output as of right now with the last activity being more then 1.5 hours earlier.


Connected 
loop started 
1555687200
1555777824
1555687500
loop started 
1555687227
1555777824
1555687527
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let me guess, the script is setting to everyone to offline, right?
The thing is that you have missed the `WHERE` clause in our `UPDATE` statement

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE player_data SET is_online = 0");
```

So it is better to review that part. It is supposed to be like this

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE player_data SET is_online = 0 WHERE id = " . $row['usr']);
```

Also there is no need to compare `strtotime($now)` and `strtotime($then)`: the `$now` and `$then` are already holding "microtime" values, so you can just do like this:

```
if ($now > $then) {
    //your code here
}
```

BTW, even if you are not using any `REQUEST` parameters, I'd suggest to use prepared statements.

Comment: @Zeusarm-- Thanks for taking the time to answer this, but it is changing nothing actually, not all rows. I also added that where clause, but also no change to the value. The really odd thing is that it was working yesterday, and I did not change anything on it.   The reason I am comparing strtotime() is because one is a timestamp from the database and it was not working until I did it this way.

Comment: @Walt yes it is true but it was so because you were comparing `strtotime`, you should just compare `$now` and `$then` as they are already holding the time values, look at your output - they are integers

Comment: Thank you, i at first missed the removal of strtotime() from $now and $then in the last IF, and that was causing the issue. It is weird that it was working Thursday but stopped on Friday, it must have somehow reverted overnight, but i am not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

Some note about your time conversions:

```
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")));
$before = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['dt'])));
```

In the first line, you convert the text `"now"` to a timestamp, then you convert it to a string, and then to a timestamp again. A short and more efficient way is to rpelace the line by

```
$now = time();
```

The second line is similar. Replace it by:

```
$before = strtotime($row['dt']);
```

I general, time conversions are much slower than usual arithmetic. So I recommend, to use always unix timestamps (seconds since epoch) and to convert them to text only, if needed at user interface.

I never use database types `date` or `timestamp`, but always int's with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). This make many much easier, especially if you need user dependent output with different time zones. Also you have no issues with DST.

Compare the output of:

```
mysql -e 'select unix_timestamp("2019-03-31 04:00")-unix_timestamp("2019-03-31 02:00")'
mysql -e 'select timediff("2019-03-31 04:00","2019-03-31 02:00")'
```

The results are

```
3600
02:00:00
```

Only the first result is correct, because of DST starts between and the difference is only 1 hour.

Comment: Wiimm  -- thank you, I will look into UNIX_TIMESTAMP() a little more once i figure out why it is not actually updating the database, or at least figure out why it broke over night. I was trying to do it that way just got confused so went with the method i used, i did take yours and @Zeusarm's advise and changed the $now and $before variables.